# Are coloured select items / combo box items a good idea?

Tags: website-design, input, selection

I have an application where the user can add a task and set a priority using a combo box. e.g. Low, Medium, High.

When this task is created and displayed to the user they see the priority as a badge. e.g. a high priority task will have a red background.

When the user is adding a task should we also colour the items in the combo box to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Drop down is not the right choice for you.

I don't think combo-box is the right control at first place here for a simple reason.

**Color coding needs to be explained**

You can't assume that your used will understand the logic behind these color coding. For all you know, he might take read *red color* as a sign for something that is `unavailable`.

**Not much info can be given in a dropdown item**

I guess the reason behind putting colors was to communicate the urgency and the expected turn-around time for these priority-type. I guess an example of the same would help, but you cannot add a lot of information in a drop-down without cluttering it.

### What you should do?

1)  Show three radio buttons `Low`, `Medium` and `High` right adjacent to each other.

2)  When user select one of them, highlight them and show a message just below it to give more insights about the certain attributes of the priority such as

> High priority tasks are expected to be solved within 24 hours

3) Put a checkbox just below this message with label

> Don't show this tooltip again.

If user selects this, don't show these messages again.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: Yeah that works. But if you haven't, I'd encourage you to explore other options.

**Long Answer**: I don't think a yes/no answer will qualify what your doing as a good idea. Anything that solves the problem is effectively a good idea. But it might be worth exploring some other questions and ideas:

- **Is your app currently cluttered?** If you've got a ton of content or the process of adding a task has a lot of steps, the goal would be to reduce friction. The idea of a select box may still work, but instead of labels maybe icons or pictures would do the trick (i.e. the common use of exclamation points to indicate priority: (!) (!!) (!!!))
- **What other actions does the user need to take?** When a user adds a task, are they clicking and setting a bunch of options? If that's the case, does the current way of selecting a priority make sense and keep users' frustration low? Another thing to consider is whether the selection harmonizes with the rest of the user flow or disrupts it somehow; from both a visual and usability standpoint it needs to make sense and fit in with everything else.
- **Are select boxes optimal?** Naturally a slider or checkbox wouldn't work out here, but have you considered a dropdown? Or like I suggested above, replacing labels with imagery or some combination?

Basically, you have options when considering how to approach it and there are a few pros and cons to consider in each case. For example, select/combo boxes have the benefit of limiting the user to one option and dropdowns have the slight downside of adding an extra action (+1 click/tap). If your time/budget allow, it would be worth doing some [A/B testing](http://blog.invisionapp.com/ab-testing-beginners-guide/) to see what users prefer and what [helps you meet your own goals](http://blog.invisionapp.com/improving-conversion-rates-ab-tests/) as far as getting the user to successfully perform actions and repeat them with ease. Hope some of that helps!